# Possible to display VS.NET 2022 IDE Toolbars docked on left with horizontal text (Instead of vertical default)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Currently, Toolbars in the Visual Studio 2022 IDE can display their text horizontally if docked to the top or bottom of the IDE's panels.

However, if they are docked to the left or right side of the IDE, the text is displayed vertically, making them difficult to read.

Is it possible to display them docked left or right with horizontal text, displaying similiar to a listview or lines, or similiar to how the Toolbox display it's list of Controls?